# CSS forms instead of tables 2011

Tags: css, forms, css-tables

I gave up on using CSS for form styling when I hit snags like requiring 3 textboxes adjacent to one another (like a phone number) or a dropdown list next to a textbox. I just couldn't come up with a reliable way to style it without good ol' TABLES.

I'm thinking about going back to CSS for form styling; I don't know:

1. Whether it's more usable to have captions on top or on the left of the field.
2. How to style the things so they place nicely even with a couple of adjacent form elements.

References? Is this still a pipe dream?

Comment: So you're saying you don't know how float or the box model works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of CSS templates designed specifically for laying out forms.

- [vessess.com](http://vesess.com/sandbox/form_template.html)
- [Uni-form](http://sprawsm.com/uni-form/)

I hope this helps point you in a productive and awesome direction. Take care.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

[image]

Basically we create a pseudotable

```
.mxrow {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
}


.mxcell {
float: left;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
height: 26px;
}

.mxcell_firstcell{
width: 25%;
}
```

And the markup would be

```
<div class = "mxrow">
  <div class = "mxcell mxcell_firstcell"><input element /></div>
  <div class = "mxcell mxcell_secondcell"><another form element/></div>
</div>
```

The individual cell classnames serve to apply specific css (my markup is a grid)

Comment: Yeah. I had a b*tch of a time doing that when I made up my first set of floating/divvy CSS for forms. Every example I seem to find online has a single label/single form control per line.

Comment: Well I did this because many javascript animations work poorly with tables. Let me fetch some css for you

Answer (score 0):

No, it is very possible, and I (and many others) have been doing it for years.

Look at `float: (left|right)` and `display: (inline|inline-block)`.

Comment: Do you use labels above the fields or to the left? What do you do when you have to put textboxes next to one another (like area code, prefix, suffix of a phone number)? Do you have examples?

Comment: @Caveatrob Check the CSS and HTML of any other site that does it. Look into floats.

Comment: @Caveatrob If you had three text boxes and you wanted them next to one another you would have each float left (likely with some padding). You would then clear: both; after. If you can provide some HTML we can mark it up with CSS for you.

Answer (score 0):

Other people give you some valid suggestions... if you still have problems you can try a form css framework like formee... http://www.formee.org/